# ngbModal.open() not working after upgrading ng-bootstrap to version 1.0.0-beta.9

Tags: angular, modal-dialog, bootstrap-modal, ng-bootstrap

My application was working fine before upgrading to angular version 5 now after upgrading angular version I must have to update ng-bootstrap otherwise it was giving me errors on ng-template. Now, I have updated both the libraries my app is working fine but as I try to open any modal it is not showing any modal not any errors on console also but the app freezes then.